# Example of simple android scheduled timer

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm using Mono for Android and I'd like to use a scheduled timer to delay execution of code slightly (250ms) before showing the soft input pad when an Activity is created.  Does anyone have a simple sample?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retracted, no answers and I ended up not using this feature.